# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' On Shapelets -platform

Tags: python, pandas, function, matplotlib, visualization

I was working on a project to show all the differents riots in the city of Paris, to have a better understanding of which place is the safer. I am using Shapelets platform dataapp and I had an issue concerning the plot of the data. I had this TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

here is my code, can someone help me?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import shapelets as sh
session = sh.sandbox()
riot = session.from_csv("riots.csv")

def build_map(riot:Dataframe,start_date:float,end_date:float)->Image:
    # This function takes a Dataframe containing all riots in Paris, and plots them into a plotly map
    import plotly.express as px
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    # Extract the riots within the dates provided by the user
    riot_in_range = riot[(riot['date'] >= start_date) & (riot['date'] <= end_date)]
    # Build the map visualization using plotly express
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(riot_in_range,
                            lat="Latitud",
                            lon="Longitud",
                            color_discrete_sequence=["brown"],
                            zoom=9.4)
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=True,
        hovermode='closest',
        mapbox=dict(
            bearing=0,
            center=dict(
                lat=48.8566,
                lon=2.3522
            ),
            pitch=0,
            zoom=9.4
        ),
    )

    # Create a matplotlib figure and display the image in the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(img)
    return Image(fig)
```

Comment: The only obvious dictionaries in this code fragment are related to the *mapbox* parameter for *fig.update_layout* Have you checked the documentation for this? Do you have the full error trace that shows the line number where this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you did here, on Shapelets we are able to compute large datasets faster by using our own data frame, if you want to pass it to another type of data you need to use riot = riot.to_pandas() you can pass your dataset into a pandas data frame. Here is the example with the code import

```
pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame

import shapelets as sh
session = sh.sandbox()
riot = session.from_csv("riots.csv")
... riot = riot.to_pandas()
def build_map(riot:Dataframe,start_date:float,end_date:float)->Image:
    # This function takes a Dataframe containing all riots in Paris, and plots them into a plotly map
    import plotly.express as px
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    # Extract the riots within the dates provided by the user
    riot_in_range = riot[(riot['date'] >= start_date) & (riot['date'] <= end_date)]
    # Build the map visualization using plotly express
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(riot_in_range,
                            lat="Latitud",
                            lon="Longitud",
                            color_discrete_sequence=["brown"],
                            zoom=9.4)
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=True,
        hovermode='closest',
        mapbox=dict(
            bearing=0,
            center=dict(
                lat=48.8566,
                lon=2.3522
            ),
            pitch=0,
            zoom=9.4
        ),
    )

    # Create a matplotlib figure and display the image in the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(img)
    return Image(fig)
```

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo